# Q: Computing an MGF of Poisson with two independent variables, does the second matter when calculating the first?

Tags: probability

I am working on a problem, in which the prompt indicates that independent random variables X and Y are independent and both follow a poisson distribution, that is X~Poisson$(\lambda)$ and Y~Poisson$(\theta)$. I am asked to compute the MGF of X. Since the different random variables have different means, can I ignore the  Y? That is, can I accurately interpret the prompt to being asking me to simply derive MGF of the poisson distribution of X?

Answer (score 0):

The computation would be the same, just with $\lambda$ instead of $\theta$ or vice versa. For completeness, here is the derivation:
\begin{align}
M_X(t) &= \mathbb E[e^{tX}]\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{tn} e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}\\
&= e^{-\lambda} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(\lambda e^t)^n}{n!}\\
&= e^{-\lambda}e^{\lambda e^t}\\
&= e^{\lambda(e^t-1)}.
\end{align}